# Scrapy: Why do I see an error that the content is not a text

Tags: python, scrapy, response

I need your help. I use scrapy and I collect all links from website X. Then I use isinstance and check if response of href is a text or not so I have a part for html and for pdf according to isinstance result, however, sometimes I receive an info (error actually) that the content is not a text and I cannot find what is going on.

Comment: We'll probably need to see your code to help

Comment: I checked step by step my code carefully and I collected all links from website with depth 2. In my code I used eg. response.css but some links presented PDF's so I did not have response.css. I added a statement with isinstance to check if it is a pdf or not :) So now problem is solved :)